# Insert null value to Sql server bigInt column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, long-integer, bigint

A table contain bigInt column named 'Phone' I want to insert null value to this column by entity frame work. I used following codes:

```
objRegister.Phone = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text  ??null  );
```

But i get this message: "`Input string was not in a correct format.`".
I change the code as shown in below:

```
objRegister.Phone = txtMobile.Text != null ?Convert.ToInt64(txtMobile.Text):((long?)null)  ;
```

I got same message : "`Input string was not in a correct format.`"

Answer (score 2):

You could try this something like this:

```
long phone;
objRegister.Phone = long.TryParse(txtPhone.Text, out phone) 
                    ? (long?)phone
                    : (long?)system.DBNullValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Int64 phoneNumber;
Int64.TryParse(txtPhone.Text, out phoneNumber) == true ? phoneNumber : DBNull.Value;
```

You can use [?: Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) with `Int64.TryParse` check whether text is convertible to `Int64`. If convertible then assign convertible value else `DBNull.Value`

Comment: This will not work - ?: operator need same type on the both expressions true and false